# C# Event getting Triggered from same Event to Create it

Tags: c#, input, event-handling, xna

I am using a Input system which manages input from all controllers, keyboard, etc. If you would like to check it out visit: http://mquandt.com/blog/2010/01/xna-input-manager-sample/

I have modified that input manager to have a queue system so that (in theory) would stop the event triggering to boil over when in the middle of a update.

**Here is a bare bones example of my issue** (This uses the XNA 4.0 framework):
http://www.mediafire.com/?9ynabpvls19u0sq

**To explain my problem better if you don't want to download:**

An input bind is created. After trigger the bind is deleted and a new one is added. But the same button press to delete and add the new one triggers the one that was added. This cycle continues with any number of binds. One->Three

What should happen is that on button press, old one is deleted and new one is added. Then after another button press add, delete, etc. One->Two->Three

I have figured out that if I add a breakpoint or a thread sleep of 100ms on the ActionDown of InputAction then it works correctly. I guess something is going wrong because it is going too fast but a thread sleep is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make DeActivate method where you can UnBind or destroy or disable your action.

Comment: I have a unload method to remove the actions in the actual project but I still have the issue. I am trying to create something for the barebones example but I am running into errors atm. That would make sense if it stacked after every press but this is the result of only one press.